# Types of convergence of a Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

I'm studying an exercise in which we must determine what kinds of convergence holds for the following martingale
$$
X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i
$$
where $Y_i$ are i.i.d standard normal distributed r.v.'s.

First, we check convergence in $L^2$, and we can see that
$$
E[X_n^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[Y_i^2] = n
$$
From which we conclude that $\sup_n E[X_n^2] = \infty$. By the $L^2$ martingale convergence theorem, we do not have convergence in $L^2$.

Then, we check convergence in $L^1$
$$
E[|X_n|] = \sqrt{n}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$
from which we again conclude that $\sup_n E[|X_n|] = \infty$.

**1) How does $\sup_n E[|X_n|] = \infty$ directly imply that $X_n$ is not uniformly integrable and so we do not have convergence in $L^1$?**

Finally, we check almost sure convergence. The exercise hints that we should show that
$$
P(\liminf X_n = -\infty) = 1, P(\limsup X_n = \infty) = 1
$$
using Kolmogorov's 0-1 law to show that $X_n$ does not converge a.s.

**2) How does one show this using Kolmogorov's 0-1 law?**

I know you're not supposed to say this in posts, but... Many thanks for your help.

Comment: A sum of i.i.d random variables cannot converge almost surely or in probability or in distribution unless they are equal to $0$ almost surely. Martingale theory is not required for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $(X_n)$ were uniformly integrable then it would be $L^1$ bounded, in the sense that  $\sup_n\|X_n\|_1<\infty$.
2. Can you show that $P(\limsup_nX_n =+\infty)>0$? (As a start, $P(\sup_{k\ge n}X_k>C)\ge P(X_n>C)$ for each $n$ and each $C>0$. That last probability tends to $1/2$ as $n\to\infty$.)

Comment: Thank you! Could you maybe verify the steps I took in (2):

$P(\lim \sup_{n \geq k} X_k > C) = \lim _{n \to \infty} P(\sup_{n \geq k} X_k > C) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n > C) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(\sum _{i=0}^{n} Y_i > C) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum _{i=0}^{n} Y_i > \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}) = P(Z > 0) = \frac{1}{2} > 0$. By Kolmogorov 0-1, since $\lim \sup X_n$ is a tail event with probability larger than 0, it must be 1?

Comment: Your steps are just fine!